# FOSS solution for storing web sessions

Tags: python, session, web-applications, pyramid

### Context

I am developing a simple web application (written in python/[pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html)) with an underlying http service as data store and with a partner integration by using backend http communication. This web application will be deployed in 3 or more nodes with a load balancer up front

### The problem

Most of the user navigation data will be stored in the session at server side (I dont want to load the browser with encrypted cookie data) and this brings the issue of how replicating the session properly. Proper load balancing and avoiding user navigation disruption is important so I dont want to use sticky sessions nor want to lose session data.

### The question

What should I use? I am thinking about storing my session data on key data stores ([memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io/), [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) or [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/architecture)) or relational data stores ([postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) or [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/))

### Edit

This is my [previous question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973299/foss-web-session-replication-solutions) where I tried pointing highs and lows on different datastores. The question got closed as it was hard to understand what is the question, so I simplified and created this one without my opinions

Comment: Depends on whether or not your session data needs to be able to survive a daemon restart or system reboot.

Comment: Yes, it should. I dont want to disrupt the user navigation in any way

Comment: In that case, you'll need to look at which backends will survive a restart. The FS-based ones (postgresql/mysql) will be okay, and the memory-based ones (memcached/redis) might be okay if you sync the data to disk every so often, but you'll always lose data if they die unexpectedly, so if you really care about that, you should probably go with an FS-based store.

Comment: I am indeed more inclined to use a memory-based key-value store. Surviving a restart should not be a problem if my datastore itself is replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase server is used a lot as distributed Session Store. As you may know Couchbase is a NoSQL database built at the top of the Memcached protocol.

This means you have the speed and reliability of Memcached but the power of the Couchbase cluster. The partitioning on the cluster is really fast since the client (or moxi, memcached proxy) is responsible of choosing the node where the session should go and replicate it asynchronously if you want to (so no impact on performance).

Some interesting pointers:
- http://www.couchbase.com/memcached
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/couchbase-usecases.html
- http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/use-cases

*Disclaimer: I am Technical Evangelist at Couchbase*

Comment: Interesting, we already use couchbase for session storage in some projects, but they all have race conditions as replication is asynchronous but in practice it does not happen because of the nature of those systems. Reading the [docs](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-architecture-clusterdesign.html) indeed couchbase is async by default but "its is designed to be synchronous". Can you give me pointers how to make it synchronous and if it is indeed a good idea. I know I will have an impact on performance, but I want to know if this impact is indeed considerable

Answer (score 1):

I use [pyramid_beaker](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/) to store session data.  It wraps the [beaker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Beaker) library into pyramid.

On production servers I use the memcached backend.  I can't remember which library I chose to power that.

A few implementation details:

1. I forked pyramid_beaker into pyramid_beaker_https, and use 2 cookies with all users.  one is "http only" that backs into public data and site viewing permissions.  the other is "https only" and used for everything under /account and any write operations.
2. I added in an "autologin" cookie as well.  If session authentication fails ( because memcached went down, and it's now invalid ) a periodically reset autologin has encrypted data to recreate the cookie sessions.
3. I track how every login happened within the session, so an autologin would require re-authentication for any /account or select write operations.

Comment: Interesting. What worries me about using memcached is losing one node and disrupting the user navigation. To use properly i will probably need to write the session to all memcached nodes and read from all of them and  get the data in the latest version

Comment: what does "disrupting the user navigation" mean ?

Comment: means that the user can get unexpected results while navigating, like having his session invalidated, being logged out, receiving a 5XX page or having connection problems caused by server side

Comment: That's why i use an autologin cookie.  if a session is invalidated, before failure you try use an encrypted cookie-based session to create a new server-side session and cookie.


You shouldn't write sessions to all memcached nodes , just one.  that's a waste of performance and memory.  memcached wasn't designed to be secure or persistent - it's a fast lightweight cache.  if you want to avoid memcache failures, you can go with mongodb or redis, both of which can be supported in beaker.

The concern with "user navigation" i had was if you're tracking users with breadcrumbs within the session.

Comment: TBH, when I switched to using autologin cookies, I actually found no need for server-side sessions at all. If a user can always be authenticated from this cookie, and you store intermediate form data in [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) with JS, then what use-cases are left that require server-side sessions?

Comment: I would say that roughly 100% of the data I have on server-side sessions is stuff that I would not want to expose client side, and most of it is data which is expensive to compute.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco Could you give a specific example?

Comment: I am inclined to agree with Jonathan. I dont want to store encrypted data on cookies as this overloads the browser communication with my servers and forces me to put static assets on different domains (to avoid queries for static assets with a big cookie inside them)

Comment: @BrunoPolaco Could you give an example of what you might want to store in server-side sessions? Your question just states "user navigation data", but if it's specific to a user, rather than a session, it sounds like you could store it in your main DB, indexed against your user table, then it would persist between logins.